# Getting the main program to know where resources are (images, data, ...)

Tags: c++, installation, cross-platform, c-preprocessor

I am currently building a C++ cross-platform game.

After a bunch of googling and reading various open-source programs' code, I still can't figure out how to pass the absolute path to installation directory at compile-time.

The idea I had was to set a "root" path for resources, allowing me to access the subdirectories, for example for saving / loading data, images, etc...

I currently have a typical open-source project organization:

- bin/  (binaries)
- include/ (header files)
- src/ (sources)
- vendor/ (external libraries)
- resources/ (images, data, etc...)
- tests/ (test programs)

But how can I possible implement this?
Using the preprocessor to pass an macro (installation path) maybe?

Is this a good practice or is there a better method to do this?

Comment: I got it to work using relative paths and a bash launching script for Unix systems. Haven't found a solution yet for Windows though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I still can't figure out how to pass the absolute path to installation directory at compile-time

You can't possibly know it beforehand during compile time. And you don't need to. Use relative paths, I see no reason why you wouldn't use them.

Comment: What I'm worried about is the working directory of the program, if my compiled program is at the root of the directory, will the working directory be the directory of the program (if for example I run it from a soft link)?

Answer (score 1):

You NEED to figure out the installation path in a platform dependent fashion. There is no portable way.

Basically:

- on Windows, use GetModuleFileNameW()
- on MacOS; use [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] (IIRC, CFBundle ends up being a lot more complicated.
- on Linux, readlink() your /proc/<pid>/exe link, and hope you haven't been launched via a hardlink. Or just hardcode the path, if you are installing via a packetmanager anyway.